# Revolution Responsive jQuery Slider image width and height change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inside the div with class `slotholder` is an image of class `defaultimg` with height and width added automatically. I want to change specially image height and width.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slotholder">
  <img class="defaultimg" alt="" src="image.png" style="width: 1399px; 
height: 724.45px; position: relative; left: -25px; opacity: 0;">
```

I have tried to change width and height in css like:

```
img .defaultimg{
  width:1570px !important;
  height:813px !important;
}
```

But isn't working. How can I change this by CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change width and height of the slider, look into the [documentation of the revolution slider script](https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/slidersettings/#gridwidth). There you'll find all the settings, including e.g. the `gridwidth` and `gridheight` options to set the size of your slider even for different viewport sizes.

So on initializing your slider, you could do the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery("#your-slider").revolution({
      gridwidth:1570,
      gridheight:813 
    }); 
});
```

If you already initialize your slider with some settings, just add the `gridwidth` and `gridheight` options.

This is a more proper solution than trying to overwrite the generated styles with CSS `!important` declarations.

Comment: why you are calling  #slider1. is it there default id?  or the slider parent div id?

Comment: `#your-slider` is the ID you are initializing your slider on. Since I don't know your exact markup, I just gave a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your selector:

> img .defaultimg

Searchs for an element with class `defaultimg` inside an `img` <sub>(which isn't possible by the way)</sub>

What you need is the **img** element with class `defaultimg` remove the space like this:

> img.defaultimg