# Change Revolution Slider's height for mobile devices through initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, revolution-slider

Please refer to the top hero section on [this page](https://eduzone.dexignzone.com/xhtml/index-5.html) for the example of Revolution Slider.

It's initialization code in this [javascript file](https://eduzone.dexignzone.com/xhtml/js/rev.slider.js) is:

```js
function dz_rev_slider_5(){
    if(dzQuery("#rev_slider_11_1").revolution == undefined){
        revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_11_1");
    }else{
        dzrevapi = dzQuery("#rev_slider_11_1").show().revolution({
            sliderType:"standard",
            sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
            dottedOverlay:"none",
            delay:9000,
            navigation: {
                onHoverStop:"off",
            },
            responsiveLevels:[1240,1240,778,778],
            visibilityLevels:[1240,1240,778,778],
            gridwidth:[1640,1640,778,778],
            gridheight:[768,768,960,960],
            lazyType:"none",
            parallax: {
                type:"mouse",
                origo:"enterpoint",
                speed:400,
              speedbg:0,
              speedls:0,
                levels:[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,55],
            },
            shadow:0,
            spinner:"spinner0",
            stopLoop:"off",
            stopAfterLoops:-1,
            stopAtSlide:-1,
            shuffle:"off",
            autoHeight:"off",
            fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
            disableProgressBar:"on",
            hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
            hideSliderAtLimit:0,
            hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
            debugMode:false,
            fallbacks: {
                simplifyAll:"off",
                nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                disableFocusListener:false,
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need to reduce the height of the slider by 30% for mobile devices. And by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381897), I tried changing the value of `gridheight` from `[768,768,960,960]` to `[768,768,672,672]`. I also tried changing the value of `autoHeight` from `"off"` to `"on"`. However, those tries do not work.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what needs to be solved here. The top hero? section where it says "How to enroll your child to class?" looks fine on mobile and I don't see the need why it should have 30% less height, as it fills the screen perfectly. There is also a carousel tag in your post, but I am seeing zero carousels on the page you linked - only thing even remotely close to a carousel could be the "our gallery" section, but even that looks more like masonry to me.

Comment: @Swiffy Sorry for not being clear enough. You are correct that it's the section where it says "How to enroll your child to class?". My business partner asked me to reduce the height because he doesn't want too much height on mobile devices. The section uses Revolution Slider, which is a plugin for creating carousels. There is currently only one carousel item, so it has no rotation and does not look like a carousel.

Comment: Wouldn't it look weird filling only 70% of the screen?  I might have time to look at it later today

Comment: @Swiffy I'm actually working on a different website which uses the same theme. The actual website's hero section is currently taller than the screen on mobile devices. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all it needed was `fullScreenOffset: "30%"`, which I found here: https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/slider-layout/

Image of the result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works! Not sure if it has a syntax for mobile devices, but I think `fullScreenOffset: window.innerWidth <= 778 ? '30%' : 0` can also do the job.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can probably hack it by making an invisible element of which height you can define with css e.g. 30vh on mobile, something else otherwise and do `fullScreenOffset: '#yourhiddenelement'`, as the documentation says you can also supply a selector. I guess the library then gets the element height and uses that.

Comment: I just tested the code, and it works. Thanks :)